# How do I forward my port to setup a remotely accessible server?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I think my task is to make sure that my router understands that any request made to my IP address at some port, say 80, must be forwarded to my computer where I have set up a server.

I have logged into my router through a web-interface, but I am unable to figure out how to perform port forwarding now. Many websites say that a port forwarding section should be available under the "advanced" section of my router. I have been unable to find that though. I did manage to find a section called "port mapping". But I am not sure how to use it if that is even the right tool.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Here are two more screenshots that may be of interest:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you expand the "NAT" section and post a screenshot of that?

Comment: Sure. Here you go

Comment: Virtual server or port trigger is probably what you want.

Comment: Virtual server it is. I was actually behind another router as well, which was what was initially throwing me off. I had to do two port forwardings essentially. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Port forwarding and port mapping are synonymous, as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

The port mapping page of your router is where you want to be.  Obviously, we cant see or interact with it and I am not familiar with that router's interface.  However, in general, you would select your router's public IP and incoming port.  Then you forward it to an the IP/hostname of a computer on your LAN and a port. This would mean someone connecting to your public IP on that port gets forwarded to the internal computer and port you selected.